WSS process generation discrepancies using different methods
I want to produce a WSS process with a certain PSD that follows an AR characteristics. I am using MATLAB to code it. When I use the ARIMA function as follow
Mdl = arima(6,0,0);
Mdl.AR = {0.9, -0.5, 0.3, -0.2, 0.1, -0.05};
Mdl.Variance = 1e-3;
Mdl.Constant = 1;
Data_length = 1e6;
Data = simulate(Mdl,Data_length);
pwelch(Data)

I get the desired data. However, When I try to produces the results using the filtering process as follow
white_noise = randn(Data_length,1);
AR_coeffs = [1, -0.9, 0.5, -0.3, 0.2, -0.1, 0.05];
filtered_signal = filter(AR_coeffs(1), AR_coeffs(2:end), white_noise);
pwelch(filtered_signal);

I get a totally different result. I know that I am doing it wrong however I don't know where! Theoretically speaking, passing a white innovation process through an AR filter will give you a colored process with the desired PSD, shaped according to the filter used. This is a famous known result that you can find in any standard random process book, for example I read the Probability Random Variables, and Stochastic Processes by Papoulis
. One can find the result in chapter 12 of the book. I am trying to simulate a situation like that to see the result but this problem happened.
Can you guys guide me through it?! Thank you

Is this a homework problem or is this a curiosity question you are working out on your own?

I'm working on a work project, this is not school project. I need to process a vast amount of data, so when using ARIMA it takes ages to produce output, I wanted to accelerate the program by filtering however the output I get is not consistent!

I think the line that's wrong is filtered_signal = filter(AR_coeffs(1), AR_coeffs(2:end), white_noise);. It should be filtered_signal = filter(1, AR_coeffs, white_noise);. Additionally, you have to scale the white noise by the model variance. If this doesn't work, let me know and I'll try to work it out some more.
